# Copying MySQL Blob Rows - to other rows with a different username

Tags: mysql, copy, blob

OK - I updated from Horde Webmail 3 to Horde Webmail 4.

In that transition, the 'horde_prefs' table now shows that the 'pref_value' field is of type BLOB.  Previously, it was of type LONGTEXT.

When setting up new accounts, I want to give all of the users default preferences before the user logs in - to ensure that they all have the proper default preferences.

Before, I simply created a PHP script with all of the default values as SQL entries - and inserted them with the username.  Now, because these are BLOB entries, I cannot do so.

So in essence, the table has four fields:

pref_uid (the username)
pref_scope (the application that the preference is set for - like horde, ingo, imp, etc)
pref_name (the name of the preference - such as last_login, last_maintenance, etc)
pref_value (the BLOB entry that contains the actual preference)

So - there might be 20+ rows for one user account and all the preferences.

I'd like to copy all of the rows from one user (say tester@test.com) to make the default preferences for the new user (say newuser@test.com)

Is there any way that this can be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible like the following:

```
insert into horde_prefs(pref_uid, pref_scope, pref_name, pref_value)
select 'newuser@test.com', pref_scope, pref_name, pref_value
from horde_prefs
where pref_uid='tester@test.com'
```

the insert into .. select .. works with blobs too.